# Does this limit exist and what's its value? $\lim_{n\to\infty}n^y\sum_ {i=1}^{n}\left[e^{-i}-\left(1-\frac{i}{n}\right)^{\!n}\right]$

Tags: calculus, limits

Find $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left\{n^y \sum_ {i=1}^{n}\left[\;e^{-i} -\left(1- \frac {i} {n}\right)^{\!n}\;\right]\right\}$$

I became interested in this problem because the YouTube series BlackPenRedPen (as part of the solution of another limit problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nPNB26hxLPc&t=7s) solved the problem in the case $y = 0$ by interchanging sum and limit without justification. I realized that the methods used to correctly solve the case $y = 0$ (i.e., the Monotone Convergence Theorem) might solve the stated problem. Before starting to work on the the problem, I was trying to ascertain if the solution was known or easier than I thought.

This problem has been criticized because I didn't supply the reason I was interested in its solution. If one needs a reason to study mathematical questions (beyond interest), then we we should stop working on The Twin Prime Conjecture, Goldbach's Conjecture, the Collatz Problem, the ABC Conjecture, etc.

Comment: For $y=1$, I get a limit of $\frac{e^2+e}{2(e-1)^3}$. If $y\lt1$, the limit would be $0$ and if $y\gt1$, the limit would be $\infty$.

Comment: Hi some person, the reason your question got put on hold is because your previous version did not show any effort on your part. Unfortunately there are people who just put their homework questions on the site and hope other people solve them. Therefore people are required to show they have put some effort into solving the problem theirselves and/or give some background on where the problem comes from. I doubt anyone on this site is averse to pure math. They are just ensuring they spend their time helping people who actually want to learn.

Comment: The original version of this question had only the limit and the directive "Find". The Math.SE community seeks to help visitors *understand* math, not to do their bidding; so, it prefers/expects questions to include something of what the asker knows about a problem. This helps answerers tailor responses to best help you, while avoiding wasting anyone's time explaining things you already know. (It also helps convince them that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you.) Your update (minus the second paragraph) is exemplary. It motivates *me*; alas, I have no insights. :/

Comment: @Robjohn I'd love to see your reasoning (especially for the case y = 1). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

**Evaluation of the Limit**

To Approximate
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\left[\,e^{-k}-\left(1-\frac kn\right)^n\,\right]\tag1
$$
note that
$$
n\log\left(1-\frac kn\right)=-k-\frac{k^2}{2n}-\frac{k^3}{3n^2}-\frac{k^4}{4n^3}-\cdots\tag2
$$
Immediately, $(2)$ implies that $\left(1-\frac kn\right)^n\lt e^{-k}$, so each term in $(1)$ is positive, and therefore, less than $e^{-k}$. Thus,
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^n\left[\,e^{-k}-\left(1-\frac kn\right)^n\,\right]
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n^{1/3}}\left[\,e^{-k}-\left(1-\frac kn\right)^n\,\right]+O\!\left(e^{-n^{1/3}}\right)\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n^{1/3}}e^{-k}\left[\,1-e^{-\frac{k^2}{2n^{\vphantom{1}}}-\frac{k^3}{3n^2}-\frac{k^4}{4n^3}-\cdots}\,\right]+O\!\left(e^{-n^{1/3}}\right)\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n^{1/3}}e^{-k}\left[\,\frac{k^2}{2n}+O\!\left(\frac{k^4}{n^2}\right)\,\right]\\
&=\frac1{2n}\sum_{k=1}^\infty k^2e^{-k}+O\!\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)\\
&=\frac1{2n}\frac{e^2+e}{(e-1)^3}+O\!\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)\tag3
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{n\sum_{k=1}^n\left[\,e^{-k}-\left(1-\frac kn\right)^n\,\right]
=\frac{e^2+e}{2(e-1)^3}+O\!\left(\frac1n\right)}\tag4
$$

---

**Calculation of the Sum Used Above**
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty k^2e^{-k}
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left[2\binom{k}{2}+\binom{k}{1}\right]e^{-k}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left[2\binom{k}{k-2}+\binom{k}{k-1}\right]e^{-k}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left[2(-1)^{k-2}\binom{-3}{k-2}+(-1)^{k-1}\binom{-2}{k-1}\right]e^{-k}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty2(-1)^k\binom{-3}{k}e^{-k-2}+\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\binom{-2}{k}e^{-k-1}\\
&=\frac{2e^{-2}}{(1-1/e)^3}+\frac{e^{-1}}{(1-1/e)^2}\\
&=\frac{e^2+e}{(e-1)^3}\tag5
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Should that $O$ term in the first line have a $O(ne^{...})$ since there are $n-n^{1/3}$ terms?

Comment: @martycohen: when summing a geometric series, the remainder is proportional to the last term, is it not?

Comment: But at the stage where you write that, it is not known that the series is geometric-like.

Comment: Another (related) method of obtaining this last infinite sum is to start with the formula for the sum of an infinite geometric series:
$$ \sum_ {k=1}^{\infty}\;x^{k}\;= \frac{x}{1-x} \text { , if }  |x|< 1. $$ Differentiating, term by term, within the open interval of convergence of this power series and multiplying by $x$, yields$$ \sum_ {k=1}^{\infty}\;kx^{k}\;= \frac{x}{(1-x)^2} \text { , if }  |x|< 1. $$ Using the same method gives $$ \sum_ {k=1}^{\infty}\;k^2x^{k}\;= \frac{x(x+1)}{(1-x)^3} \text { , if }  |x|< 1. $$ Letting $x = e^{-1}$ gives the sum.

Comment: @martycohen: each term is less than $e^{-k}$: $(2)$ shows that $\left(1-\frac kn\right)^n\le e^{-k}$, so that $0\le e^{-k}-\left(1-\frac kn\right)^n\le e^{-k}$. Thus, we do know that each term is less than that of the geometric series $e^{-k}$.

Comment: @someperson: yes, I've used a similar method [elsewhere](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1958694), but I thought a change of pace would be nice. I've even used your last formula [in a hint](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2519147).

Comment: I see now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To determine the behavior of the limit, it suffices to identify the single value of $y$ for which the limit converges to a positive real number, if exists. We claim that $y = 1$ works. More precisely, let

$$ a^{(n)}_k = n \left( e^{-k} - \left( 1 - \frac{k}{n} \right)^n \right). $$

Then we claim that

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} a^{(n)}_k = \frac{e(e+1)}{2(e-1)^3} \approx 0.996147. \tag{1} $$

To this end, the following lemma will be quite useful.

> **Lemma.** There exists a constant $ c> 0$ such that
>
> $$ 0 \leq 1 - e^x \left( 1 - \frac{x}{n} \right)^n \leq \frac{cx^2}{n} $$
>
> holds for all $n \geq 1$ and $0 \leq x \leq n$. Moreover,
>
> $$ \lim_{n\to\infty} n \left( 1 - e^x \left( 1 - \frac{x}{n} \right)^n \right) = \frac{x^2}{2}. $$

Accepting the lemma for a moment, we find that $ 0 \leq a^{(n)}_k \leq c k^2 e^{-k} $. Since $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} ck^2 e^{-k} $ converges, either by the Weierstrass M-test or by the Dominated Convergence Theorem, we get

\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} a^{(n)}_k
= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \lim_{n\to\infty} a^{(n)}_k
= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2} k^2 e^{-k}
= \frac{e(e+1)}{2(e-1)^3}.
\end{align*}

So it remains to prove the lemma:

*Proof of Lemma.* Fix $n \geq 1$ and let

$$ f(x) = 1 - e^x \left( 1 - \frac{x}{n} \right)^n. $$

Then by using the inequality $1+t\leq e^t$ which holds for any $t\in\mathbb{R}$, for $0 \leq x \leq n$ we get

$$ f'(x)
= e^x \left(1 - \frac{x}{n}\right)^{n-1} \frac{x}{n}
\leq e^{x-(n-1)\frac{x}{n}} \frac{x}{n}
\leq \frac{ex}{n}. $$

It is also clear that $f'(x) \geq 0$ on this range of $x$. Therefore the inequality follows with $c = e/2$.  As for the limit, for each fixed $x \geq 0$ we get

\begin{align*}
1 - e^x \left( 1 - \frac{x}{n} \right)^n
&= 1 - \exp\left( x + n \log\left(1 - \frac{x}{n} \right) \right) \\
&= 1 - \exp\left( - \frac{x^2}{2n} + \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right) \right) \\
&= \frac{x^2}{2n} + \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)
\end{align*}

as $n\to\infty$, and so, the desired conclusion follows.

Comment: Don't we need to prove  that $n\!\left(1-e^x\left(1-\frac xn\right)^n\right)\to\frac{x^2}2$, in addition to the bounds?

Comment: @robjohn, You are right, it deserves some explanation for those who are not familiar with this type of computation. I added some details.